# How to use bootbox with rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following:

```
<button type="button submit id="delete-selected" class="btn btn-danger></button>
```

then some more code...

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('#delete-selected').click(function(e){
 var currentButton = this;
 e.preventDefault();
   bootbox.confirm("Are you sure", function(confirmed){
   if(confirmed){
   currentButton.submit();
   }
   });
   });
</script>
```

Now everything works fine...except the button won't actually submit anything when I click OK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I realized what I was doing makes no sense...
last line should be changed to :

```
$('form').submit();
```

as obviously you can't submit a button..works now :)